# Using Or in a sql statement which is operating in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

**The Problem:**

I have 2 tables i am selecting data from one called Table_Booked which contains one record with a Username and SessionID for each time a user books, another table called Table_Sessions which contains the Session details such as SessionId,Subject,TeacherID,Day,Am_Pm and WhatYear.

Im trying to select all the records from Table_Booked where the username is the same as the current users, and i also want to get the Day & Am_Pm data for each of the sessions the user has booked or the records for the session he is trying to book. The aim is to compare the records and if any occur in the same time slot not allow the user to book the session.

**The Code:**

```
Select Table_Session.Day,Table_Session.Am_Pm,Table_Session.SessionId
From Table_Session,Table_Booked
Where Table_Booked.Username = 'G9rpenman' and  
((Table_Booked.SessionID = Table_Session.SessionId) Or (Table_Session.SessionId = 9))
```

When i run this code it fetches the information from Table_Session.SessionId = 9 twice and other tweaks have caused similarly random data selection. I cant find anything about this. Thank you for your help. If you feel i missed any crucial information out let me know and ill edit this.

Heres some screenshots of my tables with the data im using https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGw2F.jpg

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: What is the problem? The repeat records mean there are two sessions corresponding to booked table record. Add AM/PM fields to see. As you mentioned you want to retrieve **all** the booked and related sessions.

Comment: In the records there isnt a repeat. Each SessionID is an autonum so is unique and there is no sessionid 9 in the booking table so the only place it would have come from is Table_Session where there is only once instance of it making me think for some reason the data is repeating itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a JOIN statement as opposed to selecting from both tables the way you are?

What's the output of the following query :

```
SELECT
  TS.Day
  ,TS.Am_Pm
  ,TS.SessionId
FROM Table_Session TS
INNER JOIN Table_Booked TB ON TS.SessionId = TB.SessionID
   OR TS.SessionId = 9
WHERE TB.Username = 'G9rpenman'
```

Could you post some sample data from both tables so we can see what you're trying to compare to provide more help?

Comment: I added some screenshots of the tables if that would help i didn't know what format you wanted the sample data in. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The reason for the duplication is the `OR`.  I think this will do what you want:

```
Select s.Day, s.Am_Pm, s.SessionId
From Table_Booked b join
     Table_Session s 
     on s.SessionID = b.SessionId or s.SessionId = 9
Where b.Username = 'G9rpenman' ;
```

If not, you may need `union`:

```
Select s.Day, s.Am_Pm, s.SessionId
From Table_Booked b join
     Table_Session s 
     on s.SessionID = b.SessionId
Where b.Username = 'G9rpenman' 
union
Select s.Day, s.Am_Pm, s.SessionId
from Table_Session s
where s.SessionId = 9;
```

Comment: Both these bring back an error in the from clause and highlight the join syntax?

Comment: There is nothing obvious that is wrong with the `FROM` clause.  It looks like standard SQL to me.